# dragonfly+dragon naturally speaking not working

Tags: python-dragonfly

I've got Dragon Naturally Speaking 14, dragonfly, the latest natlink (4.1 or something), pywin32, python 2.7, and wxpython installed

I've got a python file with this in it in my "user configuration directory" set up by natlink

I get the natlink popup message when Dragon Naturally Speaking starts, telling me that it's working. I reset DNS 14 to ensure my "macro" (dosomething.py) is loaded.

this is the code in my dosomething.py

```
from dragonfly import Grammar, CompoundRule

# Voice command rule combining spoken form and recognition processing.
class ExampleRule(CompoundRule):
spec = "do something computer"                  # Spoken form of command.
def _process_recognition(self, node, extras):   # Callback when command is spoken.
     print "Voice command spoken."

# Create a grammar which contains and loads the command rule.
grammar = Grammar("example grammar")                # Create a grammar to contain the command    rule.
grammar.add_rule(ExampleRule())                     # Add the command rule to the grammar.
grammar.load()                                      # Load the grammar.

while True:
pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()
sleep(.1)
```

however, when I start up & activate DNS and say "do something computer" with dictation & command mode, or just command mode, the transcription box pops up, how can I tell if it's working or not? I don't think it is. What is supposed to happen? I'm new to python, I fired up the interpreter in the cmd window and no prompt like "Voice command spoken." is ever generated when I say the voice command. Is that what's supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to load up Dragonfly grammars: through Natlink, and through Windows Speech Recognition. WSR requires you to put in that while loop with `pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()`, but that won't work with Natlink. You should comment it out.

If you set this up correctly, you won't see "Voice command spoken." in any cmd prompt -- you will see it in the Natlink window.